# MS-Access: Form to enter new data has no primary key

Tags: ms-access

haven't used Access in years and having some trouble making a form to add records into a table. I've selected my table [Volunteers] then 'Make Form' and it'll open a fresh form with the first record loaded. I can scan through them fine with the navigation buttons and when I hit 'New Record' it clears all the text boxes including that of my index `Vol_ID`. My assumption is Access should pick the next number in the primary key automatically, but nothing appears in the box and when I skip it and try to enter other data I get the error message: `You must enter a value in the 'Volunteers.Vol_ID' field.`. In the few instructional videos I've seen on making new forms it typically will have `(New)` in that box and not allow user entry.

I've tried setting `DataEntry = True` and also launching it with a button containing a Macro with `Data Mode: Add` but neither seem to fix the issue. I'm sure there's something basic I'm missing here but Google has brought me no answers so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your field VOL_ID is not an auto-increment field, so you have to fill it with a correct value.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thanks. The tables were all uploaded from another project and it never occurred to me that an index wouldn't auto-increment as a default.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your bug. Goal achieved :)